# Get tensor element as int

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am writing a custom model with tf.keras and in a recurrent node I need to get the value of my 1D input as an int.
That recurrent node needs to build a 1xN tensor which elements are the result of N iterations of a function f(x).
So I created a numpy array of size N which is filled by one element at each iteration, then I convert the numpy array to a tensor.

The problem is I can't get the value of my 1D tensor as an int.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def f(x):
    return 3*x

class myLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=1, input_dim=1):
        super(myLayer, self).__init__()
        self.units = units
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units),
                                            dtype='float32'),
                                            trainable=False)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(
        shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
        initializer="random_normal",
        trainable=False,
        )        

####### IMPORTANT PART HERE ######
    def call(self, inputs):
        # In this example N = 20
        # Define numpy array
        x = np.zeros(20)
        # Set its first value to my 1D input # ERROR HERE
        x[0] = inputs[0]
        # Assign the other element of x
        for i in range(1,20):
            x[i] = f(x[i-1])
        # Cast to tensor
        return tf.constant(x, shape=(1,20))




class Linear(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=1, input_dim=20):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.units = units
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units),
                                            dtype='float32'),
                                            trainable=True)
        b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
        self.b = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(units,),
                                            dtype='float32'),
                                            trainable=True)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
            )

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b






def build_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        myLayer(),
        Linear()
    ])
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
    #model.build([1])
    return model

class PrintDot(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        if epoch % 100 == 0: print(epoch)
        print('.', end='')










train_X = np.linspace(0,99, num=100)
train_y = 2*train_X

train_X = train_X / np.linalg.norm(train_X)

model = build_model()
#print(model.summary())

epochs = 10

history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0, callbacks=[PrintDot()])

hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
hist['epoch'] = history.epoch
print(hist.tail())

# x = tf.ones((1,1)) * 0.21
# horse_layer = Horseshoe()
# y = horse_layer(x)
# print(y)
```

Comment: I tried out your code and it works without an error. What is the value of `inputs`?

Comment: Yeah it probably works like that, wait I'm uploading more code @CodePope

Comment: Could it be a problem with numpy and not with tensorflow? @CodePope